# how to add multiple owners to opportunity records?

Tags: opportunity, salesforce-id, configuration

how to add and display two owners to a single opportunity record with configuration only(
I do not want to write apex)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Opportunity teams to add multiple people to work on a opportunity record.
check [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesteam_overview.htm&type=0&language=en_US) out

It still doesn't mean an opportunity has multiple owners just that multiple members can collaborate on it. The other way is you can use sharing rules to open up access to more members.

Answer (score 0):

each record in salesforce can strictly have only one owner.

there are work arounds we are currently using and it might be useful to you.

1. Create a custom field which is a lookup to **User** object and in your business processes you address that field as a secondary owner field.
2. A record can be owned by a public group.
3. Leverage opportunity teams